# How do I run these .class files?

Tags: java

I have following files stored on my pc, but I don't know how to run any of them. I think they have something to do with java, so I tried using
`java filename` but it didn't work. Any suggestions?[image]

EDIT: Linked the file I got as is for you to try out yourself. If something works please tell me too. https://anonymousfiles.io/Hl8dKd20/

Comment: These are source code files. You can't run them without compiling first (with `javac`). It would help to know where this comes from.

Comment: This looks like a number of files extracted from a jar file which is basically a Java application. You cannot run them because they are just parts of a bigger application.

Comment: I got these files in a zip package. These were the instructions given to me https://imgur.com/a/Mlmh20Y
```Depending on which browser you are using, you might be able to enable the Java runtime extension and then tell it this is a trusted source. If you have a standalone applet viewer, you can used the attached applets (once you unzip them). You probably also will have to set up short html files to invoke them (but you can copy that from my html files).```

Comment: @Panki I got them from a website owner (who also happens to have written books on computers and programming). He had a bunch of java applets on his page which he sent to me in a zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java `.class` files contain Java bytecode to run on a JVM. Without knowing the entry point of the program (to which these `.class` files belong), you cannot "execute" individual `.class` files. If you want to see the source code (aka `.java` files) that was used to create these, try using JD, the Java decompiler: https://java-decompiler.github.io/

Edit: JD seems to be heavily outdated. Use this online decompiler instead: http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Edit #2: Apparently these `.class` files are individual applets. Follow this short guide to get them working (you will need Java 8 for `appletviewer`): https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/JavaInDOS.html (just replace DOS commands with their *nix equivalents, `nano` for `notepad`, `mv` instead of `cp`, etc.)

Comment: I just unzipped these files from a zip file. Here it is. https://anonymousfiles.io/Hl8dKd20/

Comment: @Typedragon33 these files are apparently used by a Java applet, which are deprecated since Java 8 due to security issues regarding the format. Opening the `walker.html` file with a Java-enabled browser should do the trick. If that doesn't help, install an older version of Java (the current JDK release has no applet support) and use the built-in `appletviewer` tool. The entry point for the applet seems to be `walker.class`, but you should run `appletviewer walker.html`